# Developing PHP Extensions with VS 2008 for Apache

Tags: php, visual-studio-2008

I was wondering if anyone else has tried to develop a PHP extension that can be used with apache, done on Visual Studio 2008, and what steps they had to go through to do so. I would like to not install VS 2003 to use the VC6 compiler, but if I absolutely have to, I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile your own Apache using VC9, or use one like that provided by [these folks](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/). You cannot take a PHP compiled using VC9 and load it as a module into an Apache compiled by VC6.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's windows version fully supports the 2008 compiler now, but it is not available for Apache nor is there a PHP version based on the 2008 compiler available for linux unfortunately.

Comment: But will it work with apache? I want the extension to be able to run under linux too, so I want to make it able to run with apache. The site says that you need the VC 6 compiler to run with apache, I was wondering if anyone had tried running a VC 2008 compiled extension on apache.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought it was only Apache1 that suffered from that requirement. So the answer is no, you must use VC6 for Apache HTTP Sever.